Azure Functions: BlobTrigger only on new Blobs
I have a .NET Azure Function that has a BlobTrigger that I want to trigger on new blobs. My problem is that the function does not only trigger on newly added blobs, but also on all existing blobs that do not have receipts in the control container azure-webjobs-hosts. I have implemented a simple date check as suggested here, so only new blobs get to the processing side of my code. My container has millions of rows, and I think it will be a waste for all of them to go through this, even if the function does not do anything with them.
 public static void Run(
     [BlobTrigger("%SourceContainer%/{name}", Connection= "BlobStorageSource")] Stream myBlob,
     IBinder binder,
     string name, BlobProperties properties, ILogger _logger)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation($"Started to process a blob with\n Name: \"{name}\" \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

      var blobCreatedDate = properties.CreatedOn.UtcDateTime;
      var thresholdDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);

      if (DateTime.Compare(blobCreatedDate, thresholdDate) > 0)
      {
            // do some processing
      }
      else
      {
          _logger.LogInformation("Message outside of threshold!");
      }
 }

I have found this GitHub issue that confirms that this functionality does not currently exist in Azure for BlobTrigger.
I was curious if someone got a similar issue and if there are any workarounds that I can use to achieve this functionality?

Check if this solution helps.

Thanks, but I have already tried that. I even mentioned it in my question, it is the second hyper link.

I have tried with my code and it triggered only the newly added blob, image. Existing blobs in the container

Can you check the logs through the Kudu console in Azure portal. They are in the LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> Function -> YourFunction. Usually if you have very few little blobs your function will process them even before your application insights load, so you might not see it in the logs, although they have still triggered the function. image

I would recommend to give EventGrid a shot.
There is a quite good example on the docs already explaining exactly your case
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp
Create an Event Subscription for the Blob Created event and then create a new EventGridTrigger Function.
Event based trigger are btw the recommended way for blob storage, as it has lower latency and calls on the storage account

fyi link-only answers are not valid answers. It would be better to share such a link as a comment, not as an answer. Also, adding EventGrid is a completely different solution, not related to the OP's solution.
